# Setup Quorum Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, quorum, golang

I am setting up a quorum blockchain on my computer. According to the official documentation, I have to first clone the git repo and give the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/Consensys/quorum.git
cd quorum
make all
```

I have followed the steps, but when run the

> make all

command it gave me this error:

[image: Error Photo]

Please guide me if you understand the error :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

The issue was with the go version. I had the go version 1.10 but this command needs a version greater than 1.13

Answer (score 0):

Run the following, and things will go smooth.

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install make; curl -OL https://golang.org/dl/go1.18.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz; sudo tar -C /usr/local -xvf go1.18.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz; sudo apt-get install build-essential; nano .bashrc
```

Then add these two line to the end of the file:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

export PATH=$PATH::~/quorum/build/bin

Then run:

```
source .bashrc
```

Git clone Quorum, then run make all:

```
git clone https://github.com/Consensys/quorum.git
cd quorum

make all
```